# Roxio won't let me burn Ubuntu ISO to USB drive

Tags: live-usb, iso, burning

I'm trying to burn Ubuntu 12.10 to USB drive. I downloaded the Ubuntu image fine and I want to burn it with [Roxio software](http://www.roxio.com).

But when Roxio opened up, it gave me only one option for *burn the ISO image on a CD/DVD*.  When I try to change that option, there is no other choice on the pull down menu meaning I have no idea how to get Ubuntu to my USB drive.

I'm a very, very uneducated computer user and am using Linux as a last resort to get old info off of my dead Dell laptop so be gentle with me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you follow the instructions on the [download page: "How to create a bootable USB 
stick on Windows"](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)? It explains this very question.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows and in Linux Operating Systems of all types use Unetbootin. Good for almost any Linux Operating System, I've used it to get Fedora 17 and Ubuntu 10.10, 11.10, 12.04, and 12.10.

From their [website](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) you can download it, also you'll find information to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Windows?  If so, download LiLi:
    http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
That creates a bootable Live USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

You want the Startup Disk Creator for Ubuntu. It works very well.

I'm unsure if it's installed in Ubuntu by default - if you can't see it in the Dash, go to the Ubuntu Software Center and install it.

This is if you're using Linux already - if you're currently in Windows, look [here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).